# case classes in scala gives me runtime exception

Tags: scala

I have a case class

```
case class AGG_RECON(SUBSCRIBER_ID:String , ChargingID:String ,NodeID:String, START_TIME:String, DXE_First_Report_Time:String, DXE_Last_Report_Time:String, DXE_Session_Start_Time:String, DXE_Bearer_Creation_Time:String, DXE_IMSI:String, DXE_MSISDN:String, DXE_RAT_Type:String,
                  DXE_Subscriber_Type:String, DXE_VPMN:String, DXE_ROAM_TYPE:String, DXE_APN:String, DXE_APN_Category:String, DXE_Charging_Characteristics:String, DXE_CDR_Count:String,
                  NW_First_Report_Time:String, NW_Last_Report_Time:String, NW_Session_Start_Time:String, NW_IMSI:String, NW_MSISDN:String, NW_RAT_Type:String, NW_ROAM_TYPE:String, NW_APN:String, NW_APN_Category:String, NW_Charging_Characteristics:String, NW_CDR_Count:String,
                  CHG_First_Report_Time:String, CHG_Last_Report_Time:String, CHG_Session_Start_Time:String, CHG_IMSI:String, CHG_MSISDN:String, CHG_ROAM_TYPE:String, CHG_APN:String,
                  CHG_APN_Category:String, CHG_Charging_Characteristics:String, CHG_Rate_Plan:String, CHG_Rating_Group:String, CHG_CDR_Count:String, VOL_PROBE_UL_VOL:String, VOL_PROBE_DL_VOL:String, VOL_PROBE_FREE_VOL:String, VOL_PROBE_TOT_VOL:String, VOL_NW_UL_VOL:String,VOL_NW_DL_VOL:String, VOL_NW_FREE_VOL:String, VOL_NW_TOT_VOL:String, VOL_CHG_UL_VOL:String,
                  VOL_CHG_DL_VOL:String, VOL_CHG_FREE_VOL:String, VOL_CHG_TOT_VOL:String, VOL_DXE_Session_End_Time:String, VOL_NW_Session_End_Time:String,
                  VOL_CHG_Session_End_Time:String, VOL_Session_Closed_Time:String, VOL_DXE_Is_Completed:String, VOL_NW_Is_Completed:String, VOL_CHG_Is_Completed:String, VOL_Is_Closed:String, VOL_Session_Category:String)


{
 override def toString(): String = {
val result = s"AGG_RECON_SUBSCRIBER_ID=${SUBSCRIBER_ID}, AGG_RECON_ChargingID=${ChargingID} ,AGG_RECON_NodeID=${NodeID}, AGG_RECON_START_TIME=${START_TIME}" +
  s"AGG_RECON_DXE_First_Report_Time=${DXE_First_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_DXE_Last_Report_Time=${DXE_Last_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_DXE_Session_Start_Time=${DXE_Session_Start_Time}, AGG_RECON_DXE_Bearer_Creation_Time=${DXE_Bearer_Creation_Time}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_DXE_IMSI=${DXE_IMSI}, AGG_RECON_DXE_MSISDN=${DXE_MSISDN}, AGG_RECON_DXE_RAT_Type=${DXE_RAT_Type}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_DXE_Subscriber_Type=${DXE_Subscriber_Type}, AGG_RECON_DXE_VPMN=${DXE_VPMN}, AGG_RECON_DXE_ROAM_TYPE=${DXE_ROAM_TYPE}, AGG_RECON_DXE_APN=${DXE_APN}, AGG_RECON_DXE_APN_Category=${DXE_APN_Category}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_DXE_Charging_Characteristics=${DXE_Charging_Characteristics}, AGG_RECON_DXE_CDR_Count=${DXE_CDR_Count}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_NW_First_Report_Time=${NW_First_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_NW_Last_Report_Time=${NW_Last_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_NW_Session_Start_Time=${NW_Session_Start_Time}, AGG_RECON_NW_IMSI=${NW_IMSI}, AGG_RECON_NW_MSISDN=${NW_MSISDN}, AGG_RECON_NW_RAT_Type=${NW_RAT_Type}, AGG_RECON_NW_ROAM_TYPE=${NW_ROAM_TYPE}, " +
  s"AGG_RECON_NW_APN=${NW_APN}, AGG_RECON_NW_APN_Category=${NW_APN_Category}, AGG_RECON_NW_Charging_Characteristics=${NW_Charging_Characteristics}, AGG_RECON_NW_CDR_Count=${NW_CDR_Count},"+
  s"AGG_RECON_CHG_First_Report_Time=${CHG_First_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_CHG_Last_Report_Time=${CHG_Last_Report_Time}, AGG_RECON_CHG_Session_Start_Time=${CHG_Session_Start_Time}, AGG_RECON_CHG_IMSI=${CHG_IMSI}, AGG_RECON_CHG_MSISDN=${CHG_MSISDN}, AGG_RECON_CHG_ROAM_TYPE=${CHG_ROAM_TYPE}, " +
  s"AGG_RECON_CHG_APN=${CHG_APN},"+
  s"AGG_RECON_CHG_APN_Category=${CHG_APN_Category}, AGG_RECON_CHG_Charging_Characteristics=${CHG_Charging_Characteristics}, AGG_RECON_CHG_Rate_Plan=${CHG_Rate_Plan}, AGG_RECON_CHG_Rating_Group=${CHG_Rating_Group}, AGG_RECON_CHG_CDR_Count=${CHG_CDR_Count}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_VOL_PROBE_UL_VOL=${VOL_PROBE_UL_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_PROBE_DL_VOL=${VOL_PROBE_DL_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_PROBE_FREE_VOL=${VOL_PROBE_FREE_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_PROBE_TOT_VOL=${VOL_PROBE_TOT_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_UL_VOL=${VOL_NW_UL_VOL},AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_DL_VOL=${VOL_NW_DL_VOL}, " +
  s"AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_FREE_VOL=${VOL_NW_FREE_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_TOT_VOL=${VOL_NW_TOT_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_UL_VOL=${VOL_CHG_UL_VOL}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_DL_VOL=${VOL_CHG_DL_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_FREE_VOL=${VOL_CHG_FREE_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_TOT_VOL=${VOL_CHG_TOT_VOL}, AGG_RECON_VOL_DXE_Session_End_Time=${VOL_DXE_Session_End_Time}, AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_Session_End_Time=${VOL_NW_Session_End_Time}," +
  s" AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_Session_End_Time=${VOL_CHG_Session_End_Time}, AGG_RECON_VOL_Session_Closed_Time=${VOL_Session_Closed_Time}, AGG_RECON_VOL_DXE_Is_Completed=${VOL_DXE_Is_Completed}," +
  s"AGG_RECON_VOL_NW_Is_Completed=${VOL_NW_Is_Completed}, AGG_RECON_VOL_CHG_Is_Completed=${VOL_CHG_Is_Completed}, AGG_RECON_VOL_Is_Closed=${VOL_Is_Closed}, AGG_RECON_VOL_Session_Category=${VOL_Session_Category}"
result


}
}
```

This class doesnt give me any error on compile time when I excute my application, it gives me

"excepted class or object definition" on the first bracket before toString method..I am using scala 2.11.5..I really dont know what is the problem?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are only allowed to pass 22 parameters so that could be it

Comment: I think this has been resolved in scala 2.11...even byremoving some parametres the error presists..that case class was by 12th class in the scala script file.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, it's a compilation error, not a runtime exception.
2. The empty lines before the class body tell the compiler

   ```
   case class AGG_RECON(...)
   ```

   is the complete definition, and

   ```
   { 
     override def toString = ...
   }
   ```

   is an unrelated block, but you can't have blocks on the top level of a Scala file. Remove the lines between `)` and `{` and everything will work.

Comment: Note: the Scala Community Coding Style says to put the opening braces at the end of the preceding line specifically in order to avoid this and other similar problems. While Scala has learned *a lot* from JavaScript, there are still some corner cases where you need to be aware of the rules of its Semicolon Inference, and this is one of them.

Comment: Yes, this is better.